# My LinkedList structure isn't functioning in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I've been struggling with this for a while, I can't seem to create a valid `LinkedList` data structure in C,

Here's all my structures:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int *cellsI;
    int *cellsJ;
} DataInList;

typedef struct listElement{
    DataInList dataVar;
    struct listElement *next;
} LinkedListElement;

typedef struct {
    LinkedListElement*first;
    LinkedListElement*last;
} LinkedListRoot;
```

I have a function that adds a data element to the linked list:

```
public void addDataToList(LinkedListRoot root, DataInList data) {
    LinkedListElement newElem;

    newElem.dataVar = data;
    newElem.next = NULL;

    if(root->first == NULL) {
        root->first = &newElem;
        root->last = &newElem;
    } else {
        root->last->next = &newElem;
        root->last = &newElem;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Local variables aren't called "local" for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenter said, you've *defined* newElem in the function, and on the stack as well, so you have no way to globalize it or return a permanent entry to it.  Something more along these lines. I haven't tested it yet, but it should give you the idea:

```
typedef listData struct {
    int size;
    int *cellsI;
    int *cellsJ;
} listData_t

typedef struct listElement {
    listData_t dataVar;
    struct listElement *next;
} listElement_t;

typedef struct listRoot {
    listElement_t *first;
    listElement_t *last;
} listRoot_t;

listElement_t *
addDataToList(listRoot_t *root, listData_t *data) {

    listElement_t *newElem = malloc(sizeof(struct listElement));
    if (newElem == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory\n");
        exit(-1)
    }

    newElem->dataVar = data;
    newElem->next = NULL;

    if (root->first == NULL) {
        root->first = newElem;
        root->last  = newElem;
    } else {
        root->last->next = newElem;
        root->last = newElem;
    }
    return newElem;
}
```

Comment: Look at the question "Do I cast the result  of malloc?." I'm currently unable to link to the question, sorry.

Comment: Thanks!  And don't forget to `free()` things properly.  For example, don't free a listElement without being sure to free the listData element too (and you have to allocate entries for the fields in list Data, so if they're pointers you will probably need to free those too). Generally free the pointers in the reverse order you allocated them, and set them to NULL after freeing so you don't accidentally try freeing the same memory twice (freeing NULL is harmless).

Comment: I get malloc now, it allows structs to exist outside of the stack, thanks you've helped a lot @all-about-that-base-2

Comment: @cad thanks. Looked it up. I got into the habit a long time ago, and see this comment answer to that question: "There are simply no benefits to doing it" is false. There is at least a singular benefit in that the code is more portable. Older standards require the cast. –  chacham15 Sep 25 '11 at 12:30

Comment: @cad I removed the cast, so do I get an up vote ::--))

Comment: this line: 'newElem->dataVar = data;' only copies pointer.  what is needed is to copy the whole element, using something like: memcpy( newElem->dataVar, data, sizeof listData_t );   and syntax is not correct for this line: 'typedef listData struct '  it should be: 'typedef struct listData '  However, these typedef's for struct definitions is a very poor idea.  It clutters the code, is often misleading, clutters the compiler name space, etc.  Much better to simply define the struct, then use 'struct tagname' when ever it needs to be referenced.